# Can't use boldface or italics with IPA symbols {Times New Roman}

Tags: fonts, arabic

I am writing a document with XeLaTeX. I'm using the font Times New Roman. For some reason, some Arabic IPA symbols do not italicize or appear in boldface as seen in the image.  Is there a way to resolve this issue?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
 \usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
\textbf{\textipa{Q}aadi}`\textbf{wa\textcrh ad}` `\textit{wa\textcrh ad}`

\textbf{wa\textcrh ad}

\end{document}
```

[image: S]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm new here so I'm not very familiar with the website.  Anyways, please check the code that I've added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the tipauni package. It will use your Times Font for the symbols. But I don't know how much of tipa Times support, perhaps you will have to switch to another font like Charis Sil instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{tipauni}
\begin{document}
\textbf{\textipa{Q}aadi}`\textbf{wa\textcrh ad}` `\textit{wa\textcrh ad}`

\textbf{wa\textcrh ad}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You know this, and were trying to keep your example minimal, but: Whenever I’m not sure my main font will have all the symbols I need, I add `\tracinglostchars=3` to make it an error when the font doesn’t, or at least `\tracinglostchars=2` to warn me about it. The default behavior is to silently ignore it, with a warning somewhere in the middle of a `.log` file. And there are some versions of Times New Roman from last century still in use.

Comment: Yes, my Times New Roman has the symbols (+4k other glyphs). Unrelated: Is there a reason not to be typing the characters directly, `\textbf{ʕaadi}'\textbf{waħad}`, since the IPA Extensions etc are already in the font? Just curious.

Comment: Note that the `tipauni` package also supports an optional parameter named `documentfont` which can change the font for your document while loading the package itself. e.g. `\usepackage[documentfont=Times New Roman]{tipauni}`.

Comment: @Cicada, there is no problem with your suggestion, but not everyone might be able to input the IPA characters in their source files. Also for new documents it's relatively easy, think about old documents written in TIPA which need to be typeset with the new encoding. It's a tedious task to convert all the TIPA syntax with Unicode characters. The package aims to be a compatibility-bridge between the legacy code and the new encoding. If someone is absolutely not willing to learn to type the IPA, they might learn ASCII-based TIPA and produce Unicode documents with the package.

Comment: @Niranjan Thanks for the comment. My question's background was about whether I should write  a transliteration module/environment for those who don't have/know keyboard overlays; or, alternatively, a dedicated package for inputting (any) Unicode block. There are thousands of glyphs in the Latin sets alone, though. So naming the commands will be interesting. The IPA Extensions are interesting: a cluster of variations around a few Latin glyphs, and a cluster of plain non-Latin glyphs. How would anyone choose from `aàáâãä åæāă ąǎǟǡǣ ǻǽȁȃȧ ɐɑɒάα ӑӓᶏᶐ ḁẚạảấ ầẩẫậ ắằẳẵ ặ⒜ⓐⱥ ⲁꜳꜵꜷ ꜹꜻꜽꬱꬰ`, though?

Comment: @Cicada "a dedicated package for inputting (any) Unicode block" this sounds a bit too ambitious as there are so many Unicode blocks, but if I am not mistaken TIPA provides a fair command-set for at least typing the IPA characters, what package `tipauni` does is to translate that particular command-set to produce Unicode in the output. I am the author of that package, I would love to hear any criticism regarding it, either on the [issues](https://gitlab.com/niruvt/tipauni/-/issues) page or on my email (given in the documentation) as this place doesn't seem to be appropriate for this discussion.